# Metamask showing different value from actual one when sending with web3.js

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I am sending 1125000000000000000000 token but when it connect with metamask for sign it showing 20726466.477585 value. I'm trying hard to find out the solutions but still getting same thing. below is the code.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@4.0.1-rc.1/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.5.3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    if(window.ethereum) {   
        ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        try {
            chainId = web3.utils.toHex(473861);
            ethereum.request({
                method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
                 params: [
                    {
                        chainId: chainId,
                        chainName: 'Ultra Pro Mainnet',
                        nativeCurrency: { name: 'ULTRA PRO', symbol: 'UPRO', decimals: 18 },
                        rpcUrls: ['https://mainnet-rpc.ultraproscan.io'],
                        blockExplorerUrls: ['https://ultraproscan.io/'],
                    },
                ],
            });

            web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function (accounts) {
                const address = accounts[0];
                console.log('Address:', address);

               var amt = '1125000000000000000000'; 
               window.ethereum.request({
                  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                 params: [
                    {
                      from: address,
                      to: recipient,
                      value: amt,
                      gasLimit: '0x5208',
                      maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x2540BE400',
                      maxFeePerGas: '0xu174876E800',
                    },
                  ],
                })
                .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
                .catch((error) => console.error(error));

            });
        } catch (addError) {
            window.alert("Failed, Choose the Ultra Pro Network on your wallet")
        }
    } else {
        window.alert("Install Wallet");
    }
    
</script>
```